# primitive equations on square mesh is diverging (computational fluid dynamics)

Tags: java, physics

I am trying to make a basic program for simulating the primitive equations, but something has gone wrong as it rapidly diverges. 
I used this paper as a guide: 
http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/~ross/Science/PrimEqs.html It is really good but does little to help me translate it into working code. I get the concepts(Divergence,derivatives,Material derivative(sort of),Pressure gradiant, and so on...), but it is wierd as my code keeps messing up all the time.

Both viscocity and diffusion are 0 so dont worry about them.(I have tested them separatly and both are stable)

```
void update()
{
  VDiv = Divergence(Velocity);
  PVector[][] ViscosityVector = VectorLaplace(Velocity);
  TempChange = Laplace(Temp);//diffusion operator
  PGrad = Gradient(Pressure);//pressure force
  for(int i=amountX-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    for(int j=amountY-1;j>=0;j--)
    {
      TempChange[i][j]*=Diffusion;
      TempChange[i][j]-=VDiv[i][j]*Pressure[i][j];// temp changes as volume changes

      PVector Accel=new PVector(0,Grav).sub(PVector.div(PGrad[i][j],Density[i][j]));

      Accel.add(PVector.mult(ViscosityVector[i][j],Viscosity));//viscocity
      float TS=(Density[i][j]*HeatCapacity);

      //the material derivative
      Velocity[i][j].add(Accel.mult(DT));
      Temp[i][j]+=DT*TempChange[i][j]/TS;
      if(i<amountX-1)
      {
        Temp[i+1][1]+=    Velocity[i][j].x*DT;
        Temp[i][j]-=      Velocity[i][j].x*DT;
        Density[i+1][j]+= Velocity[i][j].x*DT;
        Density[i][j]-=   Velocity[i][j].x*DT;
      }
      if(j<amountY-1)
      {
        Temp[i][j+1]+=    Velocity[i][j].y*DT;
        Temp[i][j]-=      Velocity[i][j].y*DT;
        Density[i][j+1]+= Velocity[i][j].y*DT;
        Density[i][j]-=   Velocity[i][j].y*DT;
      }
      // ideal gas law
      Pressure[i][j]=Density[i][j]*(GasConst*Temp[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure that there are no problem with the sub-functions but here they are just in case.

```
PVector[][] Gradient(float[][] Input)
{
  PVector[][] Out = new PVector[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i=0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      Out[i][j]=new PVector();
      if(j<amountY-1)
        Out[i][j].y=(-Input[i][j]+Input[i][j+1])*DY;
      if(i<amountX-1)
        Out[i][j].x=(-Input[i][j]+Input[i+1][j])*DX;

    }
  }
  return Out;
}
PVector[][] VectorLaplace(PVector[][] Input)
{
  float[][] InputX=new float[amountX][amountY];
  float[][] InputY=new float[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i =0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j =0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      InputX[i][j]=Input[i][j].x;
      InputY[i][j]=Input[i][j].y;
    }
  }
  InputX = Laplace(InputX);
  InputY = Laplace(InputY);
  PVector[][] Out = new PVector[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i =0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j =0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      Out[i][j]=new PVector(InputX[i][j],InputY[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return Out;
}
float[][] Laplace(float[][] Input)
{
  float[][] Flow = new float[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i =0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j =0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      if(i>0)
      {
        Flow[i][j]-=Input[i][j];
        Flow[i-1][j]+=Input[i][j];
      }
      if(j>0)
      {
        Flow[i][j]-=Input[i][j];
        Flow[i][j-1]+=Input[i][j];
      }
      if(i<amountX-1)
      {
        Flow[i][j]-=Input[i][j];
        Flow[i+1][j]+=Input[i][j];
      }
      if(j<amountY-1)
      {
        Flow[i][j]-=Input[i][j];
        Flow[i][j+1]+=Input[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return Flow;
}
float[][] Divergence(PVector[][] Input)
{
  float[][] Out = new float[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i=0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      if(i>0)
      {
        Out[i][j]-=(Input[i-1][j].x)*DX;
      }
      if(j>0)
      {
        Out[i][j]-=(Input[i][j-1].y)*DY;
      }
      if(i<amountX-1)
      {
        Out[i][j]+=(Input[i][j].x)*DX;
      }
      if(j<amountY-1)
      {
        Out[i][j]+=(Input[i][j].y)*DY;
      }
    }
  }
  return Out;
}
```

Can anyone see the problem with it?

Minimum code needed for failiure:

```
void update()
{
  PGrad = Gradient(Pressure);//pressure force
  for(int i=amountX-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    for(int j=amountY-1;j>=0;j--)
    {

      PVector Accel=new PVector(0,Grav).sub(PVector.div(PGrad[i][j],Density[i][j]));


      //the material derivative
      Velocity[i][j].add(Accel.mult(DT));
      if(i<amountX-1)
      {
        Density[i+1][j]+= Velocity[i][j].x*DT*Density[i][j];
        Density[i][j]-=   Velocity[i][j].x*DT*Density[i][j];
      }
      if(j<amountY-1)
      {
        Density[i][j+1]+= Velocity[i][j].y*DT*Density[i][j];
        Density[i][j]-=   Velocity[i][j].y*DT*Density[i][j];
      }
      // ideal gas law
      Pressure[i][j]=Density[i][j];
    }
  }
}

PVector[][] Gradient(float[][] Input)
{
  PVector[][] Out = new PVector[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i=0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      Out[i][j]=new PVector();
      if(j<amountY-1)
        Out[i][j].y=(-Input[i][j]+Input[i][j+1])*DY;
      if(i<amountX-1)
        Out[i][j].x=(-Input[i][j]+Input[i+1][j])*DX;

    }
  }
  return Out;
}
```

Simple 1D psudocode:

```
for(int i =0;i<N-1;i++) 
  Gradient[i]=(Pressure[i]-Pressure[i+1])*dx; 
for(int i =0;i<N;i++) 
{ 
  Accel = -Gradient[i]/Density[i]; 
  Velocity[i]+=Accel*dt; 
  if(i<N-1) 
  { 
    Density[i+1]+=Velocity*dt; 
    Density[i]-=Velocity*dt; 
  } 
  Pressure[i]=Density[i]; 
}
```

Here is the whole thing for testing. Contains temperature,viscocity and diffusion. They can be disabled if needed. Requires Processing https://processing.org/

```
int amountX=40;
int amountY=20;
float[][] Temp=new float[amountX][amountY];
float[][] Density=new float[amountX][amountY];
float[][] Pressure=new float[amountX][amountY];
PVector[][] Velocity=new PVector[amountX][amountY];
float Grav=0.05;
float GasConst=1;
float HeatCapacity=5;
float Diffusion=0.5;
float Viscosity=0.4;
float DX=1;
float DY=1;
float DT=0.001;
int Warp = 1;
float[][] VDiv;
float[][] TempChange;
PVector[][] PGrad;
void setup()
{
  size(1000,500);
  for(int i=0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      Temp[i][j]=3;
      Pressure[i][j]=exp(j*Grav/(GasConst*Temp[i][j]))*40;
      Density[i][j]=Pressure[i][j]/(GasConst*Temp[i][j]);
    }

  }
  for(int i=0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      Velocity[i][j]=new PVector(0,0);
    }
  }
  int Min=10;
  int Max=15;
  for(int i=Min;i<Max;i++)
  {
    for(int j=Min;j<Max;j++)
    {
      float x=(i-Min)/(float)(Max-Min);
      float y=(j-Min)/(float)(Max-Min);
      Temp[i][j]=lerp(3,6,exp(-(sq(2*x-1)+sq(2*y-1))*3));
    }
  }

  for(int i =0;i<0;i++)
  {
    update();
  }
}
void draw()
{
  background(201);
  for(int i = 0;i<Warp;i++)
  {
    update();
  }
  show();

}
void show()
{

  float dx=width/(float)amountX;
  float dy=height/(float)amountY;
  float dv=10*dx;
  noStroke();
  for(int i=0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      fill(Temp[i][j]*10,0,Density[i][j]*10);
      rect(dx*i,dy*j,dx,dy);

    }
  }
  stroke(255);
  for(int i=0;i<amountX;i+=1)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<amountY;j+=1)
    {
      line(dx*(i+0.5),dy*(j+0.5),dx*(i+0.5)+Velocity[i][j].x*dv,dy*(j+0.5)+Velocity[i][j].y*dv);
    }
  }
  int MouseI=(int)(mouseX/dx);
  int MouseJ=(int)(mouseY/dy);
  fill(255);
  if(MouseI>0&&MouseJ>0&&MouseI<amountX-1&&MouseJ<amountY-1)
  {
    text("Temp:"+Temp[MouseI][MouseJ],10,20);
    text("Pres:"+Pressure[MouseI][MouseJ],10,40);
    text("Dens:"+Density[MouseI][MouseJ],10,60);
  }
}
void update()
{
  VDiv = Divergence(Velocity);
  PVector[][] ViscosityVector = VectorLaplace(Velocity);
  TempChange = Laplace(Temp);//diffusion operator
  PGrad = Gradient(Pressure);//pressure force
  for(int i=amountX-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    for(int j=amountY-1;j>=0;j--)
    {
      TempChange[i][j]*=Diffusion;
      TempChange[i][j]-=VDiv[i][j]*Pressure[i][j];// temp changes as volume changes

      PVector Accel=new PVector(0,Grav).sub(PVector.div(PGrad[i][j],Density[i][j]));

      Accel.add(PVector.mult(ViscosityVector[i][j],Viscosity));//viscocity
      float TS=(Density[i][j]*HeatCapacity);

      //the material derivative
      Velocity[i][j].add(Accel.mult(DT));
      Temp[i][j]+=DT*TempChange[i][j]/TS;
      if(i<amountX-1)
      {
        Temp[i+1][1]+=    Velocity[i][j].x*DT;
        Temp[i][j]-=      Velocity[i][j].x*DT;
        Density[i+1][j]+= Velocity[i][j].x*Density[i][j];
        Density[i][j]-=   Velocity[i][j].x*Density[i][j];
      }
      if(j<amountY-1)
      {
        Temp[i][j+1]+=    Velocity[i][j].y*DT;
        Temp[i][j]-=      Velocity[i][j].y*DT;
        Density[i][j+1]+= Velocity[i][j].y*DT*Density[i][j];
        Density[i][j]-=   Velocity[i][j].y*DT*Density[i][j];
      }
      // ideal gas law
      Pressure[i][j]=Density[i][j]*(GasConst*Temp[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

PVector[][] Gradient(float[][] Input)
{
  PVector[][] Out = new PVector[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i=0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      Out[i][j]=new PVector();
      if(j<amountY-1)
        Out[i][j].y=(-Input[i][j]+Input[i][j+1])*DY;
      if(i<amountX-1)
        Out[i][j].x=(-Input[i][j]+Input[i+1][j])*DX;

    }
  }
  return Out;
}
PVector[][] VectorLaplace(PVector[][] Input)
{
  float[][] InputX=new float[amountX][amountY];
  float[][] InputY=new float[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i =0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j =0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      InputX[i][j]=Input[i][j].x;
      InputY[i][j]=Input[i][j].y;
    }
  }
  InputX = Laplace(InputX);
  InputY = Laplace(InputY);
  PVector[][] Out = new PVector[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i =0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j =0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      Out[i][j]=new PVector(InputX[i][j],InputY[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return Out;
}
float[][] Laplace(float[][] Input)
{
  float[][] Flow = new float[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i =0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j =0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      if(i>0)
      {
        Flow[i][j]-=Input[i][j];
        Flow[i-1][j]+=Input[i][j];
      }
      if(j>0)
      {
        Flow[i][j]-=Input[i][j];
        Flow[i][j-1]+=Input[i][j];
      }
      if(i<amountX-1)
      {
        Flow[i][j]-=Input[i][j];
        Flow[i+1][j]+=Input[i][j];
      }
      if(j<amountY-1)
      {
        Flow[i][j]-=Input[i][j];
        Flow[i][j+1]+=Input[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return Flow;
}
float[][] Divergence(PVector[][] Input)
{
  float[][] Out = new float[amountX][amountY];
  for(int i=0;i<amountX;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<amountY;j++)
    {
      if(i>0)
      {
        Out[i][j]-=(Input[i-1][j].x)*DX;
      }
      if(j>0)
      {
        Out[i][j]-=(Input[i][j-1].y)*DY;
      }
      if(i<amountX-1)
      {
        Out[i][j]+=(Input[i][j].x)*DX;
      }
      if(j<amountY-1)
      {
        Out[i][j]+=(Input[i][j].y)*DY;
      }
    }
  }
  return Out;
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't behaving as expected, and so the first thing that you must do (and do *before* you come here) is to isolate the source of the bug -- meaning that you need to do  intense debugging. Consider stepping through the program using your IDE's debugger, inspecting the state of key variables as you do so. This will give you valuable insights and quite possibly a decent solution. Even if you don't get a full answer, you'll be closer and can ask a better question. If you still need our help, you will need to create and post a [mcve], and tell the details of expected and observed behaviors

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels To be fair: For many sorts of simulations, the usual debugging approaches are essentially useless. There often is no point in stepping through some simulation time step that involves complex math where you simply cannot say whether a certain value is "right" or "wrong" at a certain point (except for `NaN` or so). Even more important is a small MCVE, and often the good ol' `println`s, where you can at least print messages like `"Now I'm adding these 1000 elements [...] to these [...]"` to have the chance to spot where one vector goes off the rails.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "my code keeps messing up all the time."? What is the behavior you expect vs the behavior being observed?

Comment: @Marco13: I have to bow to your expertise since I don't do simulation programming, but something sure needs to be done to first isolate the error, somehow

Comment: The problem manifests as spatial oscillations growing over time. What i mean about that is that almost immideatly there becomes a "checkerboard pattern" of high/low pressure that grows and after a few seconds turn Everything into nan values. By making the temperature constant it works a bit longer and produce a shockwave pattern that looks very promesing but after a while also fails. It feels like something is overshooting in order to produce these oscillations.

Comment: I have managed to trim down some things(like temperature). This is the minimum amount of code needed to produce the problems. I am not sure if the problems return when the old stuff gets added in but we will see... (added into main post)

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with CFD (so I cannot spot the error by looking at the code), but in other types of (physically based) simulations, the symptoms that you describe could mean that there is some energy entering the system or some sort of damping is too low, or, more likely, there are forces that are too large for the time step, and the integration method cannot cope with them. For CFD, these are **only** guesses, though. Maybe the viscosity should *not* be zero? Maybe the time step has to be smaller? (Sorry, likely not the targeted advice you're looking for...)

Comment: @Marco13 It is not exactly the correct reasons i think but you are on the right track. My theory is that the pressure gradient cauces a force that pushes apart fluid at higher pressure, but it is then pulled back due to the same equation, and becauce of no viscocity and a bad integrator it increaces in amplitede caucing these problems, so what I need is essentially a better integrator. Does anyone know of a simple one that does not increase in energy like this?

Comment: I managed to construct a dead simple 1 dimensional psudocode variant of this problem to help with picking out the problem:
`for(int i =0;i<N-1;i++)
  Gradient[i]=(Pressure[i]-Pressure[i+1])*dx;
for(int i =0;i<N;i++)
{
  Accel = -Gradient[i]/Density[i];
  Velocity[i]+=Accel*dt;
  if(i<N-1)
  {
    Density[i+1]+=Velocity*dt;
    Density[i]-=Velocity*dt;
  }
  Pressure[i]=Density[i];
}` I dont know how to put linebreaks here :(

Comment: @Eriksonn, if you have updated code, edit it into the question; there it can be properly formatted.

Comment: No line breaks in comments. If you could extend your *question* with an [MCVE], including some initial data, basically something that people can copy+paste, compile and start to see some console output that later turns into `NaN`, people could investigate it more easily. This could either be your actual code, or the simplified 1D one. Otherwise, people could only read the code and basically *guess*. That's not an error that you spot easily by just reading the code.

Comment: So i should put the whole code in the main post so you guys can run it yourself? Should it be with or without the temperature and viscocity? I use processing as code editor btw.

Comment: I added the whole program so that you can run it.